# Android Facebook LoginButton does not update login state if I login from webform

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have an app that allows users to post on Facebook.
In the options screen I have a LoginButton that I can use to login and it will remember the state. It will change to Logout once I logged in.
If I try to share something without being logged in (using the button in options screen), the Facebook web form appears and I login there. The problem is that the LoginButton in the options screen does not update it's state to say "Logout".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your "options screen" you should check is there any `AccessToken` already like this

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null &&
            com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null) {
        imgFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                imgFacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgFacebookDeactive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook has Logout successfulley!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    } else {
        imgFacebook.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgFacebookDeactive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgFacebookDeactive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Facebook already Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I check my CurrentAccessToken and CurrentProfile then, if it's not null that's mean there is an account has been logged in. I call the `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` to logout facebook.

Comment: AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() is null in the options screen. I checked that. Still, if I try to share again, it does not ask me to login.